# Exit user impersonation by clicking a link

Tags: symfony, impersonation

I'm trying to create a link to exit a user impersonation session. 
When the user clicks the exit link, he should get redirected to the admin dashboard and be logged in as himself again.

I have created a link as followed: (This doesn't work as I get an access denied screen because I'm still logged in as that normal user which doesn't have permissions to see the admin dashboard)

```
<a href="{{ path('AdminBundle_dashboard', {_switch_user: '_exit'}) }}">Exit</a>
```

But I have also tried creating the link with an absoute link and that works!

```
<a href="http://domain.com/app_dev.php/admin?_switch_user=_exit">Exit</a>
```

Although the docs say it should work by using path()
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#impersonating-a-user

Comment: What is the output of {{ path('AdminBundle_dashboard', {_switch_user: '_exit'}) }}? Are you sure your previous role was admin when clicking on the first link?

Comment: Output is http://domain.com/app_dev.php/admin/?_switch_user=_exit. Yes I'm sure :)

Comment: So output is the same as the static link but both links provide different outcome?

Comment: well almost. The dynamic link puts a "/" after "admin"

Comment: I've implemented this feature once and I've used the Symfony routing generator (same as path in twig) without a problem. I suppose you get the exception when visiting the url domain.com/app_dev.php/admin/?_switch_user=_exit, not when rendering the path?

Comment: I've solved it by just putting <a href="/app_dev.php/admin?_switch_user=_exit">Exit</a>